# Do lists store handles / references or are they value types?

Tags: c#, .net

Obviously if I made a list and filled it with "new object()" then it would be storing the memory for the object, but what if I made a list composed of only objects that were already defined, would this list essentially be a list of handles, or would all the data / memory copy to the list?

I just want to know so I can write code to be more clean, like if it's actually copying the memory then I'll do things differently because I don't want it to make memory copies, that causes lag.

Does your answer also apply to arrays?

Comment: The list will store whatever generic type you assign to it. Be it a value type or a reference type. If you have `List<int>`, it will be storing the `int`s as values (because int is a value type). If you were to make a `List<SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` is a class (reference type), then the `reference` will be stored in the list. The actual memory for `SomeClass` will be allocated on the heap and a reference to the data will be stored in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obviously if I made a list and filled it with "new object()" then it would be storing the memory for the object,

No, it would be storing a reference to the object. The value of any expression in C# is a value type value, a reference, or a pointer. *Never* an actual object.

So this:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
objects.Add(new object());
```

is equivalent to this:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
object foo = new object();
objects.Add(foo);
```

In both cases, the list will contain a reference to the object. This isn't just the case for lists - it's vital you understand it for assignment, parameter passing - *anything* where a reference is copied, basically. So as a simple example:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = sb1;
// sb1 and sb2 now have the same value: a *reference* to an object
sb2.Append("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(sb1); // Prints Hello
```

See my articles on [value and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html), and [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.